# Too many fields, cannot see them in qgis2web

Tags: image

I have too many fields, so they can't all be seen, is there a work around for this? see this image [image]

As you can see the info "bleeds" over and you cannot see it, I need to reshape that as a box instead of a big rectangle or lower the font.

Comment: you can switch off (or hide) these fields if not required in QGIS, the question is do you need all of them?

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers or Leaflet? If you're using Leaflet, you should be able to adjust the formatting of the popup, I can write a full answer for that if you are